# Can anyone help me to fix this weird behaviour with windows desktops?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user32

So, I was exploring the `user32` functions when I discovered desktops. I wrote a small program about them:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main () 
{
    HDESK newdesk = CreateDesktopA("newdesktop", NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);
    HDESK olddesk = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
    SetThreadDesktop(newdesk);
    SwitchDesktop(newdesk);
    MessageBoxA(GetDesktopWindow(), "I am in a new desktop!", "New Desktop", MB_OK);
    SetThreadDesktop(olddesk);
    SwitchDesktop(olddesk);
    CloseDesktop(newdesk);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

It works fine as a normal user. However, when I try to launch it as an administrator, the desktop gets created, it gets activated, but the message box does not appear.

I don't know if it's necessary to mention, but the User Account Control is at its default settings, and I am using Windows 10.

I also tried that on different operating system versions with the User Account Control feature (Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 11) and they all had the same exact problem, while I expected it to run fine as a normal user and as an admin.

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: None of those functions [return a value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-switchdesktop)?  If so, why are you not checking the return values to ensure they are successful?  -- *Return value:
If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.  To get extended error information, call GetLastError*

Comment: I checked the code, and the only functions that could cause a problem are setthreaddesktop and messageboxa. And as i said, all the code works just fine as a regular user, so why not as an administrator?

Comment: Are you assuming those functions returned no error, are you are actually checking the return values?

Comment: No. But based on the behaviour of the code,  i was able to find out the 2 functions that could cause this problem. I never assumed that they returned no error.

Comment: With the exception of `ExitProcess`, **every** function you call can fail. You will want to check each and every function call to see whether it succeeded or failed. Are you doing that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with the code and Windows Virtual Desktop is managed by [IVirtualDesktopManager](https://github.com/MScholtes/VirtualDesktop/blob/18966f130f1eb2caa56663c7ac7ce2863dfd84d1/VirtualDesktop.cs#L188). You should find out the error message.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT virtual desktops are a completely different feature, they simply [show/hide windows on the original desktop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171002-00/?p=97116), they don't actually create new desktops, like the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Ok. I found out the function that is causing the problem: it is SetThreadDesktop and it returns : 'The Requested Resource Is In Use'. The only thing is that i do not call any functions involving gui applications before the desktop functions.